# Delete email template folder with a destructive package

Tags: destructivechanges.xml, deliverability

I want to delete a email folder (empty) with a destructive package but I can't make this work.

I made a .zip with my 2 files :

**package.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

**destructiveChangePost.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <name>Folder</name>
        <members>my_email_folder</members>       
    </types>

</Package>
```

When I try to deploy with Workbench, the folder isn't deleted :

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to do it in that way?

Comment: When you use workbench , have you made `Check Only` flag as true?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal No, I let all the boxes uncheck

Comment: are there any emails inside the folder?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal The folder is empty

Comment: You are trying to delete file-folder and not email template folder. Can you try this instead?

<name>EmailTemplate</name>

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It works !!! It's a bit weird to use "EmailTemplate" to act on the folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email Template folder is not `Folder` Object but just `EmailTemplate`

Changing destructive.xml file include email template folder makes it delete it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <name>Folder</name>
        <members>EmailTemplate</members>       
    </types>

</Package>
```